# Inspecting how $PATH gets created

Tags: shell, shell-scripting, path

Is it possible to "listen" to a variable's value during the start of a new shell?

I have a script that checks for the $PATH variable in the typical places, but I'd like to try something different. Here's what I'm thinking:

Instead of just guessing at where $PATH is set, I'd like to spawn a new shell for the user in the background, by running a command called something like "path-inspector". path-inspector spawns a new shell for the current user and listens to the $PATH variable. Maybe it sets $PATH to an empty string first, but anytime $PATH is modified, the command echo's out the filename with line number that modified $PATH. It would be like setting breakpoints and having a debugger specifically for $PATH.

I still feel like I'm in the stage where I don't know have a clear picture of how this could be implemented. Here's what I'm aware of that I'd need to address:

- [Subshells can't export *variables* back to the parent](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/gotchas.html#PARCHILDPROBREF) so I would need to devise an approach to echo'ing or reporting the results.
- I don't know of any builtin that "listens to" a variable, so I'd need an approach to this as well. Possibly injecting a command before and/or after each command in the new shell is run to echo or tee the output?
- Environmental variables aren't just these big global things, they are created for each shell, and more specifically, [for each process](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html#ENVREF). They'll be similar, but I'd need to at least be aware that, for example, a non-interactive shell might not have the same $PATH as a login shell. So if the command creates a "subshell", it may or may not use the same settings as a normal login shell.
- Different shells. bash, sh, zsh, fish, etc.

I'm open to feedback of any kind: "Its already been done", "It's not possible", or "you'd also need to know about this". etc.

Comment: Are we talking Linux here?  If so, have you thought of using /proc/PID/environ?

Comment: most commonly osx, though I'd like to support both. I'm not familiar with proc. Can you expand on /prod/PID/environ?

Answer (score 0):

`ksh` actually implements a neat feature called [`discipline functions`](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html) which basically allows you to attach callbacks to setting or referencing a variable:

```
$ cat t.sh
#!/bin/ksh

PATH=

function PATH.set
{
    echo "new PATH in ${.sh.file}:${.sh.lineno}:"
    echo "  old = [${PATH}]"
    echo "  new = [${.sh.value}]"
}

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
PATH=$PATH:$PATH
```

.

```
$ ./t.sh
new PATH in t.sh:12:
  old = []
  new = [/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin]
new PATH in t.sh:13:
  old = [/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin]
  new = [/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin]
```

Similarly, `PATH.get` would be executed everytime `$PATH` is referenced.

Unfortunately, as it seems you cannot export functions in `ksh93`, this would restrict the callback to the current script limiting its overall usefulness.

Comment: Very cool feature. I tested it out and found that if you use ${.sh.value} inside the function it shows what the value is being changed to, so I made an edit to your answer. Will definitely play around with this and see if it can accomplish what I need.

Comment: @brockangelo Good catch, fixed the typo :-)